# Different behaviour between `/REG/g` and `new RegExp()`?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to match the components in a Rust compiler error output. This is the regexp I am using:

```
let newErrorRegex = /(warning|error|note|help)(?:\[(.*)\])?\: (.*)\s+--> (.*):(\d+):(\d+)\n(?:((?:.+\n)+)\.+)?(?:[\d\s]+\|.*)*((?:\s+=.*)+)?/g;
```

It works fine but it's too long, so I'd like to break it into multiple lines. Then I tried `new RegExp()`:

```
let newErrorRegex = new RegExp('(warning|error|note|help)(?:\[(.*)\])?\: (.*)\s+--> (.*):(\d+):(\d+)\n(?:((?:.+\n)+)\.+)?(?:[\d\s]+\|.*)*((?:\s+=.*)+)?', 'g');
const match = newErrorRegex.exec(output);
```

But it's not working this time! However some simpler instances have no such issues, e.g.,

```
let testRegexp = new RegExp('abc', 'g');
const match = testRegexp.exec('abcabc');
```

What's the difference between `/REG/g` and `new RegExp()`? How could I fix this issue? I have tried both TypeScript 1.8.7 and 2.0 (although I don't think it's related...).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

FYI, a sample of Rust compiler output could be: https://regex101.com/r/vKFWYW/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line you're using the syntax `/foo/` that let the `\` be what they are.

With `new Regex('foo')` you what to escape the backslashes because it's a string literal. Which leads to:

```
let newErrorRegex = new RegExp('(warning|error|note|help)(?:\\[(.*)\\])?\\: (.*)\\s+--> (.*):(\\d+):(\\d+)\\n(?:((?:.+\\n)+)\\.+)?(?:[\\d\\s]+\\|.*)*((?:\\s+=.*)+)?', 'g');
```

Comment: @Soviut 37sec, pretty fast edit :)

Comment: I was practically watching you add it in real time ;) You should add the corrected version of the expression with the escaped slashes to your answer for completeness.

Comment: @Soviut done :)

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer! I am feeling like a noob right now lol

Comment: @FrederickZhang that's how we all learn ;)